# Iterative solution of recurrence relation $T(n)=4T(\frac{n}{2})+\frac{n^3}{log_2n}$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

Please help me to find the Time Complexity of the recurrence relation $T(n)=4T(\frac{n}{2})+\frac{n^3}{log_2n}$ using iterative method.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Also the iteration method only allows you to "guess" the solution but it doesn't give a formal proof of its correctness (at some point the iteration it will involve some magic dots to skip over from the terms you have already unrolleed to the base case). Once you have your guess you should prove its correctness via induction.  (By the way, recurrence equations do not have time complexities. Algorithms do.)

Comment: @Steven I have tried to solve the recurrence relation. And I am stuck at $T(n)=n^2(1+\sum_{x=1}^{log_2n}\frac{2^x}{x})$. I don't know how to calculate the summation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $n$ is a power of $2$ and that $T(1)=1$.

$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 4 T(n/2) + \frac{n^3}{\log n} \\
&= 4 \left(4 T(n/4) + \frac{(n/2)^3}{ \log (n/2)}\right) + \frac{n^3}{\log n} \\
&= 16 T(n/4) + \frac{n^3}{2 \log(n/2)} + \frac{n^3}{\log n} \\
&=16 \left(4 T(n/8) + \frac{(n/4)^3}{ \log (n/4)}\right)  + \frac{n^3}{2 \log (n/2)} + \frac{n^3}{\log n} \\
&=64T(n/8) +\frac{n^3}{4\log(n/4)} + \frac{n^3}{2 \log (n/2)} + \frac{n^3}{\log n}  \\
&= \dots \\
& = 4^i T(n/2^i) + \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \frac{n^3}{2^j \log(n/2^j)}
\end{align*}.
$$

Choosing $i=\log n$:
$$
T(n) = n^2 + \sum_{j=0}^{\log n - 1} \frac{n^3}{2^j \log(n/2^j)}.
$$

We can now obtain a lower bound by only considering the first term of the sum (i.e., $j=0$):
$$
T(n) \ge n^2 + \frac{n^3}{\log n} = \Omega\left(\frac{n^3}{\log n}\right).
$$

For the upper bound observe that, for $t \ge 4$:
$$\frac{t^3}{\log t} =
\frac{(2t)^3}{8 (\log 2t - 1)} = \frac{(2t)^3}{8 \cdot \log 2t \cdot \frac{\log 2t - 1}{\log 2t}} \le \frac{3}{16} \cdot \frac{(2t)^3}{\log 2t}
$$
Showing that, for $0 \le j \le \log n -2$:
$$
\frac{n^3}{2^j \log(n/2^j)} \le \left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^j \frac{n^3}{\log n}.
$$

Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= n^2 + 2n^2 + \sum_{j=0}^{\log n - 2} \frac{n^3}{2^j \log(n/2^j)}  \\
&\le  3n^2
+
\frac{n^3}{\log n} \sum_{j=0}^{\log n - 2} \left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^j
\le 3n^2 + \frac{n^3}{\log n} \cdot \frac{16}{13} = O\left(\frac{n^3}{\log n}\right).
\end{align*}
$$

If you are fine with using the Master theorem instead of iteration then you can check that, for any $0 <\varepsilon < 1$, $\frac{n^3}{\log n} = \Omega(n^{\log_2 4 + \varepsilon})$ and that the regularity condition holds, implying that $T(n) = \Theta(\frac{n^3}{\log n})$.

Answer (score 0):

With $n=2^m$, let $S(m):=4^{-m}T(2^m)$. The recurrence turns to

$$4^mS(m)=4^{m-1}4S(m-1)+\frac{8^m}{m}$$

or
$$S(m)=S(m-1)+\frac{2^m}{m}.$$

Then refer to this answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/153922/16034