# Solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(\frac{n}{2})+\frac{n}{\log n}$ without master theorem

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

Suppose given  the recurrence $$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{2})+\frac{n}{\log n}.$$
I think the answer is
$$T(n)=O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right).$$
because
$$T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log n-1}    \frac{n}{2^i(\log n-i)}$$
but how we can show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n-1}    \frac{n}{2^i(\log n-i}=O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$?

Comment: The terms in your summation are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

With $n:=2^m$, the recurrence turns to

$$S(m)=S(m-1)+\frac{2^m}m$$

and

$$S(m)=S_0+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^k}k.$$

Splitting the sum and keeping the smallest denominators, we get
$$S_0+\sum_{k=1}^{m/2-1}\frac{2^k}k+\sum_{k=m/2}^m\frac{2^k}k\le S_0+\sum_{k=1}^{m/2-1}2^k+\frac 2m\sum_{k=m/2}^m2^k\\=O\left(2^{m/2}+\dfrac{2^m}m\right)=O\left(\frac{2^m}m\right).$$

Then indeed

$$T(n)=O\left(\frac n{\log n}\right).$$